# Hiding Flex AdvancedDataGridColumn

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an mx:AdvancedDataGrid that is inside of an mx:canvas and I am assigning its dataProvider programatically within my AS script. Once the dataProvider is set, the columns are populated based on whichever amount of columns my query returns. Is there a way to make some of the returned columns invisible from the get go? I have tried to programatically hide the columns ( as depicted below ), but I've run into timing issues where the page has not yet completed loading and therefore I end up referencing a null object.

```
    myGrid.columns[1].visible = false; // This won't always work due to timing issues

    <mx:Canvas id="myCanvas" 
                       height="100%" 
                       horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                       verticalScrollPolicy="off">
                <mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="myGrid"                             
                                         doubleClickEnabled="true"
                                         iconFunction="reportListIconFunction" 
                                         labelField="ReportTitle"  sortableColumns="false"/>
    </mx:Canvas>
```

Also, I am not able to use   as I get a "Could not resolve  to a component implementation error. I think this might be to the fact that the data grid I'm working with is inside a canvas. Thanks for your help. I'm new to Flex so i definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually just able to solve the problem by putting my "myGrid.columns[1].visible = false;" code inside onCreationComplete(). Very simple solution. Sorry, totally new to Flex...